# How to change a predefined PWM frequency?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, dc-motor, motor-controller

I have a controller which has predefined PWM frequency of 150 Hz. This output is used to control a motor. However, I want to use another PWM frequency, but I can not change the PWM frequency on my controller via the control software. Only the duty cycle is changable.

What is an easy and cheap way to be able to use a different PWM frequency?

My motor is a 9V DC motor.

My controller is called TXT and uses [this firmware.](https://github.com/ftCommunity/ftcommunity-TXT)

Comment: What is this controller? Why you want to change it? You have the full source code out there, why can't you change it?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a "quick and easy" way.

A quick look around the ftcommunity project and related [forums](http://forum.ftcommunity.de/index.php) says that the low PWM frequency is often a problem.

The most common solution seems to be to attach an external PWM generator to the TX controller.

Some of the posts mention using the [Adafruit 1438.](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1438)

The newer versions are I2C, and have a built in PWM generator.  Frequency and duty cycle controlled through I2C.

The TX seems to have an I2C port and software (judging by the forum comments.)